# Parent/Grandparent Page Title for Widget Title

Tags: wordpress, widget

Using page list with parent, child and grandchild pages for current nav section as widget in sidebar. Parent page displays correctly as widget title when on child page, but when on grandchild page widget title changes to child page title. Regardless of what I've tried to get back to the root parent, the result is always the same as using this:

```
php global $post; $thispage = $post->ID;
php $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent); echo $parent_title;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, at least for my purposes:

```
php echo get_page(array_pop(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)))->post_title;
```

Comment: Yeah, I had discovered the get_ancestors function far too late. If this is what works for you, go ahead and mark this as answered. Sorry I couldn't get the answer you needed in time.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** So it seems I've gone ahead and reinvented the wheel (badly, might I add) when Wordpress already has a [Get Ancestors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) function built into their framework. Utilizing it is about as easy as you can get. This should do what you want:

```
if($ancestors = array_reverse(get_ancestors(get_the_ID(), 'page')))
    echo get_the_title($ancestors[0]);
else
    echo get_the_title(get_the_ID());
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. This does work for the child pages, but on a grandchild page I end up with no sidebar widget menu at all - like it isn't seeing any parent at that level.